# Expresso Store PHP Error with reports

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I'm getting a PHP error when generating reports. Any idea what this means?

EE 2.5.3 w/ Expresso Store 1.6.2 / IIS 7 / PHP 5.3.6

```
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid CRT parameters detected
Filename: store/mcp.store.php
Line Number: 2248
```

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? Does it happen to HTML reports or only when you try to export as PDF?

Comment: This is only an issue with custom date ranges. From Store > Reports > Orders Reports -- placed in Custom Range. Press view Report. This outputs a repeated php error: 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid CRT parameters detected

Filename: store/mcp.store.php

Line Number: 2248

Comment: Other reports output fine -- even the CSV and PDF options.

Comment: From googling that error, it looks like a problem formatting dates, which only happens on windows, so that would make sense. I'll investigate and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Store which only appears on servers running Windows/IIS. It is to do with PHP handling date formatting differently on Windows.

It will be fixed in the next version of Store.